# Nativescript build for mobile breaks if imports in TS files are not relevant paths

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I try to build or run a mobile version of my web app which is builded with Angular via Nativescript I get multiple compiler errors like:

> src/app/search/search.module.ts(5,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/common/pipes/pipes.module'.

This doesn't happen when I import the files from a relative path.
For example instead of: `app/common/pipes/pipes.module` if I do `../../../common/pipes/pipes.module` I will not get any errors.

Even that the fix seems easy this is something that I would prefer not to change as relative paths make our life more difficult if we want to refactor our app or move things around.

Does anyone has a solution with this? It happens only when I build the app with nativescript cli and not with angular cli.

Comment: relative path is a good practice and u should follow that why you want static path in your app ?

Comment: Static path helps us avoid mistakes in the team, especially when we have to refactor and move some components around. Still my question is not related with the purpose of relative vs static path but indeed the issue with nativescript build issue with static paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update your `paths` config within `compilerOptions` from your `tsconfig.json`

```
   "paths": {
        "~/*": [
            "./src/*"
        ],
        "*": [
            "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
            "./node_modules/*"
        ]
    }
```

Now I can import anything inside `src` as `import ... from '~/app/...'`

Comment: Oh I had to import them from `~/app/` instead of `app/`, thanks.

Comment: Make sure your tsconfig for web is in sync.